# Sharepoint: Upload outlook template to Sharepoint - and have it open in Outlook when clicked as opposed to a preview

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, msg, oft

We have SharePoint as part of Microsoft 365. While I can upload Outlook templates and messages to the document library (obviously), there seems to be no way to have them actually open in Outlook. The template files (.oft) won't open at all, and messages (.msg) open in preview mode and must be downloaded to be used in Outlook. The email messages go out once a day, and the recipients can change weekly, so just downloading it once and keeping it locally won't work.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is by default.

There is a [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/40334668--msg-files-stored-in-sharepoint-won-t-open-in-outl) about this requirement, you can vote up it.

Comment: No, it doesn't work by default, and there is no answer to the question link you sent.